# Exporting multiplied raster layers as one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I want to use QGIS to create a map from a DEM. I want color and hillshade, so I did the following:

- Duplicated my DEM
- For the style of the copied layer, I selected hillshade, and the multiply option
- For the style of the original layer, I selected Singleband Pseudocolor, chose my ramp, classified and chose the multiply option as well

This gives me the visual output I want. How do I export this as a single layer, keeping the color and hillshade?

I want to export the result as a Leaflet map, but using the qgis2web plugin only shows the top layer (singleband pseudocolor).

What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose that leaflet will not support Multiply. So the only option will be,  to export your map canvas (project->import/export) with the "world file option" to an image and reload the image as a new layer which will show both layers as definded. Then export it to leaflet...by the way. you only need one times the multiply option for your top layer.

Comment: Sometimes, it makes sense to duplicate the layer with the color-ramp so that you have 3 layers: 1 x hillshade, 2 x color ramp. Than multiply the color-ramp-layer with it's duplicate - that can improve the colors (maybe reduce transparency to avoid extreme effects). As for exporting options, you could try creating a new (single) raster with the raster calculator, but I guess you will not be able to reproduce the visuals you have with layer blending modes and combination of these two (three) layers.